# Designating a Boolean as true from a raw_input string?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I have a simple `if` `elif` `else` statement that relies upon the input of the user.

```
options = ['Try to jump the gap', 'Go back to the entryway']
print "You can:"
for x in options:
    print "\t:>%s" % x
choice = raw_input("What do you do?")
if  'try' in choice:
    print "You try to jump the gap and fail."
    print "You fall into the pool of acid while shrieking in pain."
    print "You dissolve"
    dead()
elif 'go' in choice:
    change()
    entrywaymain()
else:
    unknown()
    change()
    poolroomclosed()
```

The code works when the user inputs just 'try' or 'go'.
However, if the user inputs the full statements, either "try to jump the gap' or 'go back to the entryway', they will always get the if value and will die. So, how do I code so that the boolean will activate  with only word from that string in the user input.

Comment: Maybe `choice.lower() == 'try'` or `choice.lower().startswith('try')`?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because "Go back to the en**try**way" contains "try".

Currently, simply using `if "try" in choice:` is pretty error-prone for this reason. You'd be better off checking the beginning of the string using the methods mentioned by the others:

```
choice.split()[0].lower() == "try"
# Returns True for "try to jump" but not for "tryto jump"

choice.split(" ")[0].lower() == "try"
# Equivalent to the above

choice.lower().startswith("try")
# Returns True for "try to jump" and "tryto jump"
```

(Capitalization doesn't matter for any of these snippets.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the first word of `choice`, you can do something like :

```
choice.split(' ')[0]
```

You can also put in lower case :

```
choice.split(' ')[0].lower()
```

EDIT :
jweyrich's solution seems more elegant (I did not know there was a `startwith` string method), I would just modify his solution to `choice.lower().startswith('try')`, so it works with your example (Python strings are case sensitive).